# How to redirect a category to another link?

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, redirect

I have an extension in my store that I can upload posts with this and it has a link in the top menu that' name is **blog**.
In the menu, I have a category that's name is News and I want to redirect it to blog. This means that when clicking on News on the menu it shows me **blog**.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply go to `catalog > URL rewrite management` and choose "add rewrite" then choose your "custom" from dropdown.

In **Request path** section enter your `category link` (ex. if url is www.example.com/category then enter `category` only)
and in **Target path** enter your target url  (ex. if blog url is "www.example.com/blog" then just "blog")

Hope this helps.

**Update 1**

If you receive `Request Path for Specified Store already exists.` then you need to go to `catalog > Url rewrite management` and then edit that category by finding it in that grid page.

**Update 2**

If none of above work for your try to add redirect in your `.htaccess` file

```
Redirect 301 /category.html http://www.example.com/blog.html
```

**Explanation**

For each store magento needs unique identity for `request path`, so you cannot add another and by default magento disables `category rewrites request path field`. So `.htaccess` is the best option here unless you update it from database directly. And good thing with the `.htaccess` is you can simply remove it when you need it but if you directly edited your database then will need to edit it again when removing.

Comment: I can't found target section? which field do you mean?

Comment: Plez check my updated answer.

Comment: I get this error: Request Path for Specified Store already exists.

Comment: I see, that means you already have rewrite for this category, which you will need to edit instead of adding new. See my updated answer then.

Comment: So I can't edit target path in it, I just can edit request path.what can I do?

Comment: Sorry, please check another update.

Comment: That's worked. So for this error: `Request Path for Specified Store already exists`, we just can add `Redirect 302 /category.html http://www.example.com/blog.html` in `.htaccess` and we don't have any other solution except this?

Comment: For each store magento needs unique identity for request path, so you cannot add another and by default magento disables category rewrites `request path field`. So `.htaccess` is the best option here unless you update it from database directly. And good thing with the `.htaccess` is you can simply remove it when you need it.

Comment: Hi Adrash, I have a problem now, that day when I add that line in `.htaccess` every thing worked ok but when today I check the store I see that the box of latest product and sales product in home page doesn't show!!! I remove that line from `.htaccess` and problem solved. Why it does happen? Now how can I do the redirect?

Comment: can you paste what you added in .htaccess and where exactly? as well as also give me url plez

Comment: `Redirect 302 /news.html http://example.com/blog` in `.htaccess` before `</IfModule>` .

Comment: It should be inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, just confirming. Can you replace "302" with 301

Comment: Yes I added it inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, I replace 302 with 301 and now every thing works good, if I have any problem I ask you again. Thank you so much Adarsh.

Comment: Can do redirect with above method, what  needs to be done that URL remains same with Redirect?  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145017/magento-2-rediection-from-category-page-to-cms-page-without-changing-url

Comment: Sorry if old but 
you wrote under paragraph two that because there is already a rewrite rule for the category you need to use .htaccess , but its only because you need to create a new rule where the reference is the destination of the original category rule , this will enable you to create a new rule for the original address and refer to which ever address you want .
This post shows it very well :
http://www.entroducing.com/view/redirect-magento-category-to-a-url

Answer (score 2):

Go to `catalog -> URL rewrite management`, create "add url rewrite".

choose "custom" in "Create URL Rewrite:" field.

In `Request path` give your "News menu url".

In `target path` give your "blog url".

save changes.

If you get any error, find your request path in the grid.If it already exists try edit that one or delete that one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing I've found that works - but it's not the cleanest method. It goes in your `Custom Design > Custom Layout Update` area in the category you want to redirect FROM.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="SOME.BLOCK.NAME.HERE">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("https://www.WEBSITE.com/CUSTOM-REDIRECT");</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by simply deleting the existing rewrite rule in `catalog -> URL rewrite management`.

Click on my category menu in the frontend you will see that the url is not rewritten anymore, you should see something like `catalog/category/view/s/xxx/id/xx`/ when you access the category page.

Add a new rule (type 301), with the request path `catalog/category/view/s/xxx/id/xx/`, and target path being your CMS page.