# Magento 2: Redirect from Category Page to CMS Page

Tags: magento2, category, cms, redirect, htaccess

I already gone through [How to redirect a category to another link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/how-to-redirect-a-category-to-another-link)

Still i have issue. In my `.htaccess` , in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` before end of `</IfModule>`

i wrote

```
Redirect 301 /subcart/product.html http://localhost/magento2/testcmspage
```

Comment: Did you tried in URL rewrite management?

Comment: Yes. I tried. But it's giving same error as mentioned in reference link. So no other way apart from `htaccess`

Comment: yes. You have to change the product.html which is existing already to other one and create the new URL rewrite for product.html. I also got the same error in URL rewrite. Then I changed the existing URL and the redirection is working

Comment: Can you please post your detailed answer with explanation please

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1) Under **Marketing-> URL rewrites** search `products.html` under `Request Path` column. Then edit that and change the request path URL as products-old.html and then click save.

2) Create the new URL rewrite as like below screenshot and then click save.

[image]

Comment: Nope it's not working for Me. It's adding that value but on frontend it's not redirecting

Comment: Did you tried reindex and clearing cache and generation folders?

Comment: Yes i already tried

Answer (score 0):

the trick to this is:

1. Go to ROOT folder of magento 2
2. Open .httaccess file
3. Add following line (**IMPORTANT!!! MAKE SURE TO ADD IT TO BEGINING
   OF THE FILE, FIRST LINE IS BEST, OTHERWISE IT WILL NOT WORK**, Replace the first link with your category link and second the page you wish to redirect to):

   ```
   RewriteRule catalog/category/view/s/example/id/213/ https://example.com/example [L,R=301]
   ```

Save and enter following commands in the command tool:

```
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I was fighting with this, but all this time the trick was to add the line at the beggining of the .htaccess file. I was adding it at the end (last line)