# Magento 2: Rediection from Category page to CMS Page Without Changing URL

Tags: magento2, category, cms, redirect, htaccess

I have tried below in `.htaccess` which works fine

I'm redirecting Category page to CMS Page

```
Redirect /my-page/contact-us.html /contact
```

Above works fine, but will change URL as it's `Redirect`.

**I don't want to change URL.**

So i tried below code, but seems not working

```
RewriteRule ^customer/account/login/?$ /customer/account/create/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^customer/account/login/?(.*)$ /customer/account/create/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

You can even shorten it down to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?contact.* / [P]
```

Comment: Not working for me . From `Redirect /customized-services.html /customized-services` converting `RewriteRule ^/?customized-services.* /customized-services [P]`
1st is Category Page 2nd is CMS Page URL

Comment: have you set `RewriteCond` ?

Comment: Tried with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customized-services.html`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /customized-services [P]` will redirect me to Category Page not CMS